# Keep only the Cells that contain certain value

Tags: r, excel, subset

I have a dataset "Cases" with 16000+ rows that contains 25 columns with various diagnosis codes, 1 code per column. I also have a key which contains 56 unique diagnosis codes. I need to parse out the codes that match those in the key. How can I condense this down to a more concise dataset? In general, only one code should remain. Unfortunately I don't have any code to share because I don't know where to start. I am open to using Excel or R to do this. Thank you in advance and apologies in advance for how vague this question is, I honestly just don't know where to start.

```
Principal.DX    DX2     DX3    DX4     DX5     DX6   DX7
1       D57.01  J18.9 Z86.711 Z79.01 Z87.891   E55.9      
2        E66.2  J18.9  J96.21 J96.22  Z68.45   J20.9   I10
3     T82.7XXA A41.01   J18.9  N18.6 L03.114 L02.414 I12.0
4        J18.9 J96.21   R57.1  I42.0  I50.32   K52.1 N17.9
5       J10.08  J12.9  H66.91  L30.9                      
6      J15.212  E84.0   E44.0  J44.1   J15.6  K86.81
```

So in this example, let's say I only need to keep the values "J96.21", "J12.9", and "E55.9".

Comment: please provide a representative subset of your data

Comment: What do you want to keep? Rows that contain specific code? Columns that contain specific code? Only *cells* that contain specific code?

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 I want to keep only the cell that contains one of the codes of interest.

Comment: Can you be specific on what your expected output would look like? In R, I would likely start with replacing the cells without those values to be `NA`, but that does not change the dimensions of the `data.frame`. If this is what you are expecting, please state this. Otherwise, if you are expecting the frame to become more compact, then there will be problems with asymmetric removals, resulting in a frame with inconsistent column lengths (which is no longer a frame).